# Sorting in pandas by multiple column without distorting index

Tags: python, pandas, sorting

I have just started out with Pandas and I am trying to do a multilevel sorting of data by columns. I have four columns in my data: STNAME, CTYNAME, CENSUS2010POP, SUMLEV. I want to set the index of my data by columns: STNAME, CTYNAME and then sort the data by CENSUS2010POP. After I set the index the appears like in pic 1 ([before sorting by CENSUS2010POP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yWW0K.png)) and when I sort and the data appears like pic 2 ([After sorting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S44xA.png)). You can see Indices are messy and no longer sorted serially.

I have read out a few posts including this one ([Sorting a multi-index while respecting its index structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26350723/sorting-a-multi-index-while-respecting-its-index-structure)) which dates back to five years ago and does not work while I write them. I am yet to learn the group by function.

Could you please tell me a way I can achieve this?

ps: I come from a accounting/finance background and very new to coding. I have just completed two Python course including PY4E.com

used this below code to set the index

```
census_dfq6 = census_dfq6.set_index(['STNAME','CTYNAME'])
```

and, used the below code to sort the data:

```
census_dfq6 = census_dfq6.sort_values (by = ['CENSUS2010POP'], ascending = [False] )
```

sample data I am working, I would love to share the csv file but I don't see a way to share this.

```
STNAME,CTYNAME,CENSUS2010POP,SUMLEV
Alabama,Autauga County,54571,50
Alabama,Baldwin County,182265,50
Alabama,Barbour County,27457,50
Alabama,Bibb County,22915,50
Alabama,Blount County,57322,50
Alaska,Aleutians East Borough,3141,50
Alaska,Aleutians West Census Area,5561,50
Alaska,Anchorage Municipality,291826,50
Alaska,Bethel Census Area,17013,50
Wyoming,Platte County,8667,50
Wyoming,Sheridan County,29116,50
Wyoming,Sublette County,10247,50
Wyoming,Sweetwater County,43806,50
Wyoming,Teton County,21294,50
Wyoming,Uinta County,21118,50
Wyoming,Washakie County,8533,50
Wyoming,Weston County,7208,50
```

Required End Result:

```
STNAME,CTYNAME,CENSUS2010POP,SUMLEV
Alabama,Autauga County,54571,50
Alabama,Baldwin County,182265,50
Alabama,Barbour County,27457,50
Alabama,Bibb County,22915,50
Alabama,Blount County,57322,50
Alaska,Aleutians East Borough,3141,50
Alaska,Aleutians West Census Area,5561,50
Alaska,Anchorage Municipality,291826,50
Alaska,Bethel Census Area,17013,50
Wyoming,Platte County,8667,50
Wyoming,Sheridan County,29116,50
Wyoming,Sublette County,10247,50
Wyoming,Sweetwater County,43806,50
Wyoming,Teton County,21294,50
Wyoming,Uinta County,21118,50
Wyoming,Washakie County,8533,50
Wyoming,Weston County,7208,50
```

Comment: what end result are you trying to get?

Comment: I should have clarified it better. Please see my required end result I have added now.