# Sort aggregated column in multiindex dataframe within groups

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

Taking inspiration from the data [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17242970/multi-index-sorting-in-pandas) we have the following Series/Dataframe

`df = data.groupby(["Manufacturer","Product Name","Product Launch Data"]).sum("total")`

```
                                                 total
Manufacturer Product Name Product Launch Date       
Apple        iPad         2010-04-03              30
             iPod         2001-10-23              34
Samsung      Galaxy       2009-04-27              24
             Galaxy Tab   2010-09-02              22
```

How do we sort after `total` while still keeping the groups i.e ending up with:

```
                                                 total
Manufacturer Product Name Product Launch Date       
Apple        iPad         2010-04-03              30
             iPod         2001-10-23              34
Samsung      Galaxy Tab   2010-09-02              22
             Galaxy       2009-04-27              24
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In last pandas versions is possible sorting by levels and columns names together, so here working:

```
df = df.sort_values(['Manufacturer','total'])
print (df)
                                               total
Manufacturer Product Name Product Launch Date       
Apple        iPad         2010-04-03              30
             iPod         2001-10-23              34
Samsung      Galaxy Tab   2010-09-02              22
             Galaxy       2009-04-27              24
```

Comment: Thanks! How come I have not seen that - I have been starring at the documentation for so long now